How to change crosshair size / color change in edit mode
for the life of me how does one change this setting? V 4.1

There is no such setting

Not a solution, but... This works for Windows 11. I did it for Windows 10, but I cant find where I did it. The probable downside for you is that if you make a change, the change applies to everything you do on your computer. You can change the pointer size and choose among a few colors for it. In Windows 11 go to Settings->Accessibility->Mouse pointer and touch. I don't use the white pointer, but in Blender in Edit mode the crosshair changes to white.

Not really a Blender solution, but if you are using Windows 10, the options that @curious_1 mentioned are under Settings > Ease of Access > Cursor & Pointer.

See this posting.

@DuarteFarrajotaRamos That looks like an answer to me :)

@Joachim A very terse and bare one. I'd much prefer curious_1 one as an actual answer, since it does present a possible workaround
